# Is it better to use GL_FIXED or GL_FLOAT on Android

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, fixed-point

I would have assumed that `GL_FIXED` was faster, but the iPhone docs actually say to use `GL_FLOAT` because `GL_FIXED` has to be converted to `GL_FLOAT`. Is it the same on Android? I suppose it varies by phone, but what about recent popular ones (Nexus One, Droid/Milestone, etc.)?

Bonus points: This appears to be completely undocumented (e.g. search google for `GL_FIXED`!) but where is the 'point' in `GL_FIXED`? I.e. how much is `(GL_FIXED)1` worth?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Andreas says, which one is faster depends on the hardware rather than on the gl standard.  In general, you can expect GL_FLOAT to probably be the better choice when true hardware acceleration is used.  GL_FIXED will usually be faster if the work is done in software on a CPU with poor or zero support for floating point math.

GL_FIXED is a 32 bit format, using 16.16 semantics.  So 1 as a GL_FIXED value would be 0x10000.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with android, it will depend on the actual GPU in the telephone in question. Generally I would think that `GL_FLOAT` will be faster on modern GPUs.